# Where can I download the Windows installer for Drush?

Tags: 8, drush

I cannot find the link where to download Drush windows installer.
Can anyone tell me if there is or how to do?

I am using Drupal 8.1 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install it using composer as specified here:

https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/docs/install.md

After installation, make sure to run and use the drush command inside Git's shell only (the shell environment bundled with Git for Windows)

Comment: thanks for the indication, but I stopped and I have not figured out what is wrong.
I saw the video and I vusto using bash, I will,
I installed git
From the command line I wrote:
git clone --branch master http://git.drupal.org/project/devel.git
Then follow the directions of the site Drush I wrote:
  export PATH = "$ HOME / .composer / vendor / bin: $ PATH"

Any command you write back to me this error:
bash: composer: command not found

What do you suggest me?

thank you

Comment: Installazione - Windows # con l'installer # Questo è il modo più semplice per ottenere Compositore installare sulla vostra macchina. Scaricare ed eseguire compositore-Setup.exe. Sarà installare l'ultima versione Composer e impostare il percorso in modo che si può chiamare compositore da qualsiasi directory nella riga di comando. Nota: Chiudere il terminale corrente. l'utilizzo di test con un nuovo terminale: Questo è importante, dal momento che il PATH solo viene caricato quando il terminale si avvia.

Comment: @Gaetano In Windows, setting PATH environment variables happens via the `SET` command or the GUI by running `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables` from command line. Run this command and set the PATH variable there.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Acquia Dev Desktop](https://www.acquia.com/downloads). Drush is Pre Installed